# Replace URL Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Edit: Just to be clear, my question is: How to replace the first url with the paste one if the input has already a url as it's value?

I want to replace the url string if the user pastes a string that contains url (must start with a url). On document load, the input has a url already as it's value. For example: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions.

If user copy string has a url in it, replace the first url string from input.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

We will replace the first one with the user paste.

I'v done that using code below but nor working as i want.

```
$(document).on('paste', 'input.link', function(){
    var $element = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        var $val = $element.val();
        var $exp = /(https?:\/\/(?:w{3}\.)?stackoverflow\.com\/?)+/g;

        if($val.match($exp)){
            var $count = 0;

            $val = $val.replace($exp, function(match) {
                $count++;

                if($count > 1) {
                    return match;
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            });

            $element.val($val);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt9zn/

Comment: I... do not understand what your question is.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Just updated my question.

Comment: Still not clear... If you can mention a couple of examples..!!

Comment: @Bhavik I really don't know how you could not understand this explained question... You can see my fiddle yes? That's the example. In short: if the input has a url value in it, if the user pastes a url that input (at the end of the old url), replace the old url with the new one that the user have pasted. Am i clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to be sure, I read your requirements as:

1. On paste into input
2. IF existing value is url AND pasted value is url
3. replace existing url with pasted url

If so, the following will do that continually on paste:

```
function escape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

var url_match = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)/;

$('input').on('paste', function() {
    if (url_match.test($(this).val())) {
        var current_value = $(this).val(),
            match_current = new RegExp('^('+escape(current_value)+')(.*)$');
        setTimeout(function() {
            var matches = $('input').val().match(match_current);
            if (matches && matches.length >= 3 && url_match.test(matches[2])) {
                $('input').val(matches[2]);
            }
        },100);
    }
});
```

See the working [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/datchley/Lt9zn/3/)

Comment: No problem.  That was fun little snippet to work on.